# TypeError: db.collection is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express

I am trying to post data to database that I have created on mLab and I am getting this error but I don't know whats going wrong.I also have read previously asked question on this topic but I am not able to solve my error as I am new to this. So here I am posting the code which I am trying to implement and It is taken from this tutorial https://medium.freecodecamp.com/building-a-simple-node-js-api-in-under-30-minutes-a07ea9e390d2.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const db = require('./config/db');


const app = express();

const port = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extened:true}));


MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err,database) =>{

    if (err) return console.log(err)
    require('./app/routes')(app,{});
    app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log("We are live on"+port); 
    });

})
```

db.js

```
module.exports = {
  url : "mongodb://JayTanna:Jay12345@ds147510.mlab.com:47510/testing"
};
```

index.js

```
const noteroutes = require('./note_routes');

module.exports = function(app,db)
{
    noteroutes(app,db);

};
```

note_routes.js

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
    const note = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
    db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
      if (err) { 
        res.send({ 'error': 'An error has occurred' }); 
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: in your index.js, I can't see where you declare `db` - are you require-ing it?

Comment: If you want to learn mongoDB, than you can download NPM **Mongo Models**. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-models The beautifull node package, you can open Mongo Models codes and learn from there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your server.js, you are passing empty object where you need to pass database as second argument as its what your routes/index.js export function expects.

PFB updated server.js :

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const db = require('./config/db');

const app = express();

const port = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err,database) =>{

    if (err) return console.log(err)
    //require('./app/routes')(app,{});
    //check below line changed
     require('./app/routes')(app, database);
    app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log("We are live on"+port); 
    });

});
```

Comment: Req.body.body and req.body.title  both are giving me 'undefind', Do you see any thing wrong in this??

Comment: You need to add app.use(bodyParser.json()); middleware

Comment: The title is coming from post or get it is it a URL slug parameter?

Comment: No. When I do console.log(req.body) it is giving me title and body both but when I do console.log(req.body.body) it is giving me undefind.

Comment: Just making sure I am getting this correct, when you do console.log(req.body), you are getting properties title and body and then you are trying to log req.body.title and req.body.body. Can you please double check if those are properties of req.body ot just of the req ?

Comment: then req.title gives undefind. request.body gives me { 'title ': 'My note title ', 'body ': 'What a great note ' } this response. I want to extract them into separate variable.

Comment: check this line: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extened:true})); 
'extened' is a typo.

Answer (score 237):

So I voted for the answer which said to just go down to mongodb 2.2.33 because I tried it and it worked, but then I felt weird about just downgrading to fix a problem so I found the solution which allows you to keep version >= 3.0. If anyone finds this issue and their problem wasn't passing in a blank reference like the accepted answer, try this solution out.

When you run..

```
MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err,database) =>{ }
```

In mongodb version >= 3.0, That `database` variable is actually the parent object of the object you are trying to access with `database.collection('whatever')`. To access the correct object, you need to reference your database name, for me that was by doing

```
MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err,database) =>{ 
  const myAwesomeDB = database.db('myDatabaseNameAsAString')
  myAwesomeDB.collection('theCollectionIwantToAccess')
}
```

This fixed my errors when running my node.js server, hopefully this helps somebody who doesn't just want to downgrade their version.

(also, if you don't know your db name for some reason, just do a console.log(database) and you'll see it as an object attribute)

---

EDIT (June 2018):

According to [this](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#connectCallback), the callback actually returns the connected client of the database, instead of the database itself.

Therefore, to get the database instance, we need to use [this method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#db), which takes in a `dbName`. In the documentation it said `If not provided, use database name from connection string.`, as mentioned by @divillysausages in the comments below.

In short, we should call `database.db().collection('theCollectionIwantToAccess');` if the dbName is provided by url, where the `database` is actually `client` for better understanding

Comment: I tried the same thing but db.collection query is called before database.db('dbname') gives the db object. and thus getting the same error msg

Comment: although, database.db('dbname') gives correct object but the before that the query is already executed giving the error

Comment: It works like a charm for me since the problem was still occuring even though I have filled database parameter as indicated in accepted answer...

Comment: This worked for me. Apparently they changed the API and forgot to update the docs. How did you figure this out?

Comment: [here's](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/3.0.0/CHANGES_3.0.0.md#api-changes) a list of the breaking changes between V2 and V3

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm really glad you didn't settle for downgrade because I ran into the same problem and glad I found your answer!

Comment: This is an excellent fix. Downgrading or anything else seems just too tacky for me. This is the right way of doing this. Thank you @Jake

Comment: I'm kind of baffled that MongoDB's own docs don't even show this.

Comment: Thanks for this. Using 3.0.2 and going crazy to figure out the problem.

Comment: FYI, if your connection string contains the DB name (e.g. `mongodb://localhost:27107/MyDB`, then it'll be set as the default on the returned MongoClient (`database` in this example). This lets you call `database.db()` to get the actual DB

Comment: @Yoav New URL for breaking changes - https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/CHANGES_3.0.0.md

Answer (score 36):

The error is in the mongodb library. Try to install version `2.2.33` of `mongodb`. Delete your `node_modules` directory and add

```
"dependencies": {
   "mongodb": "^2.2.33"
}
```

Then

```
npm install
```

and there you are

Comment: ... unbelievable that the issue is with the version on mongodb. my package.json had 3.0.0-rc0 installed by default through `npm install mongodb --save` great catch @yaxartes

Comment: @DavidAnderton  The issue isn't with MongoDB, it's just a syntax issue. See my solution below if you do not want to downgrade mongodb, hope it helps!

Comment: @antikytheraton downgrading is not a best solution, need the correct syntex

Comment: @Ganesh I am agree with you. This solution was my way to solve this issue when mongo was updated directly to version 3 at that time

Answer (score 23):

```
MongoClient.connect(uristring, function (err, database) {
      var db=database.db('chatroomApp');
      var collections=db.collection('chats');
});
```

Need to Get the Database first before trying to access the collections.

Answer (score 15):

According to the mongo document, we need to change the connection as bellow,

```
The legacy operation
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, db) => {
    // Database returned
});

is replaced with
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, client) => {
    // Client returned
    var db = client.db('test');
});
```

Don't need to downgrade the mongo version :)

Comment: so how ever deep I pass the url it will give me only client. isn't it?

Answer (score 12):

Uninstalling existing mongodb package and reinstalling using the following commands resolved the issues for me. :)

```
npm uninstall mongodb --save

npm install mongodb@2.2.33 --save
```

**PS:** Thanks to @MihirBhende and @yaxartes

**FYI,**

Prefer non-rc releases from https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/releases, if you are new to the field.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same issue. It looks like the mongodb driver module for node was updated since the video was created. I found the code below in the docs which works.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/<dbName>';
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, db) => {
   db.collection('<collection-name>').find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {

    // Print the documents returned
    docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    });

    // Close the DB
    db.close();
    });

});
```

is replaced with

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

  var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'; // remove the db name.
    MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
       var db = client.db(dbName);
       db.collection('<collection-name>').find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {

        // Print the documents returned
        docs.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
        });

        // Close the DB
        client.close();
        });

    });
```

Here is a [link](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/quick-start/quick-start/) to the latest docs in case we run into further syntax issues.

Answer (score 4):

For the recent version I was using `"mongodb": "^3.1.3"` Below code solved my issue

in `server.js`

```
MongoCLient.connect(db.url,(err,client)=>{
    var db=client.db('notable123');
    if(err){
    return console.log(err);
    }
    require('./server-app/routes')(app,db);
    app.listen(port, ()=> {
        console.log("we are live on : "+ port);
    })

})
```

and your post code is like

```
module.exports = function(app,db) {
    app.post('/notes',(req,res)=>{
        const note= {text: req.body.body,title:req.body.title};
        db.collection('notes').insertOne(note,(err,result)=>{
            if(err) {
                res.send({"error":"Ann error has occured"}); 
            } else {
                res.send(result.ops[0])
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
module.exports = function(app, db) {
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
  const note = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
  db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
...
```

db -> client

```
module.exports = function(app, client) {
  var db = client.db("name");
  app.post('/notes', (req, res) => {
  const note = { text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title };
  db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot to Dilum Darshana! Your advice helped a lot. I just want to add, that, if you use promises it will looks like this:

```
let db;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost/collectionName').then(connection => {
    db = connection.db('collectionName');
    app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("App started on port 3000");
    }); 
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('ERROR:', error);
});
```

Comment: Should the url include collection name?  I'm looking at http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html and it does not seem the url format supports that unless your DB and collection are named the same thing?

Comment: I think yes, because of you need to take the certain object for your goals, and the certain object is the part of certain collection anyway, which is the part of database. Of course, if I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In your package.json.

make sure the following versions look like this:

```
"nodemon": "^1.12.1"
"mongodb": "^2.2.33"
```

the above nodemon and mongodb versions work together without any errors.
so your package.json should look something like this:

```
    {
  "name": "myapi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Json Api",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "Riley Manda",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "mongodb": "^2.2.33"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.12.1"
  }
}
```

dont forget to run **npm install** after downgrading

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue as well, I was following a tutorial in which the presenter was using the collection as a function.  It never worked for me.  What I discovered was that the presenter was using version 2.3.4 of the mongodb npm module.  the module is well into version 3.x.x now.   When I changed the package.json file to request the 2.x.x version of the mogodb npm module, suddenly everything worked.

What I believed happened was that the module was altered to change the collection into a different object.  Don't know how to use the new version but if you specify that you want the 2.x.x version, the old way should work.  Specifically I can confirm that (coming from my package.json file, "dependencies" section) "mongodb": "^2.2.31" works.

Best way:

```
$> npm install mongodb@2.2.31 --save
```

Answer (score 1):

```
MongoClient.connect(db.url,(err,database) =>{
    if (err) return console.log(err)
    //require('./app/routes')(app,{});
    //try this 
     require('./app/routes')(app,database);
    app.listen(port,() => {
        console.log("We are live on"+port); 
    });
})
```

here you have to include the database in the empty {}.

or

you can also try installing mongodb to latest which will solve the issue.

```
npm install mongodb@2.2.33 --save
```

else npm install add dependency of   "mongodb": "^2.2.33"  in node modules.

Answer (score 0):

Working code using:

```
npm version 6.0.1,
Node version 10.1.0
"body-parser": "^1.18.3",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"mongodb": "^3.1.0-beta4"
"nodemon": "^1.17.4"
```

Here is `server.js` code:

```
const express       = require('express');
const MongoClient   = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const bodyParser    = require('body-parser');
const db            = require('./config/db');
const app           = express();
const port          = 8000;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true }))
MongoClient.connect(db.url, { useNewUrlParser: true },  (err, client)=>{
    var db = client.db('notable');
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    require('./app/routes')(app, client);
    app.listen(port,()=>{
        console.log('we are live at '+ port);
    });
})
```

Here is `config/db.js` code:

```
module.exports = {
    url:"mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017"
}
```

Here is `routes/note_routes.js`:

```
 var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
 module.exports= function (app, client) {
        var db = client.db('notable');
        //find One
        app.get('/notes/:id', (req, res)=>{
                const id =req.params.id;
                const details ={'_id': new ObjectId(id)}
                db.collection('notes').findOne(details, (err, item)=>{
                    if(err)
                    {
                        res.send({'error':"An error has occured"})
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send(item)
                    }
                });
            });
            //update rout
            app.put('/notes/:id', (req, res)=>{
                const id =req.params.id;
                const details ={'_id': new ObjectId(id)}
                const note ={text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title};
                db.collection('notes').update(details, note, (err, item)=>{
                    if(err)
                    {
                        res.send({'error':"An error has occured"})
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send(item)
                    }
                });
            });

            //delete route
            app.delete('/notes/:id', (req, res)=>{
                const id =req.params.id;
                const details ={'_id': new ObjectId(id)}
                db.collection('notes').remove(details, (err, item)=>{
                    if(err)
                    {
                        res.send({'error':"An error has occured"})
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send("Note "+id+"deleted!")
                    }
                });
            });
            //insert route
            app.post('/notes', (req, res)=>{
                const note ={text: req.body.body, title: req.body.title};
                db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, results)=>{
                    if(err)
                    {
                        res.send({'error':"An error has occured"})
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        res.send(results.ops[0])
                    }
                });

            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dont use database name in connection url:**

```
const mongo_url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
```

**Instead use below method:**

```
MongoClient.connect(mongo_url , { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err)
        const  db =  client.db('student')
        const collection = db.collection('test_student');
        console.log(req.body);
        collection.insertOne(req.body,(err,result)=>{
            if(err){
                res.json(err);
            }
            res.json(result);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please add more to the answer that explains why the OP should use your code and how it solves their issue!

Answer (score 0):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

//connection url

 const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';

 MongoClient.connect(url,{useNewUrlParser: true},(err,client)=> {
  if(err) {
    return console.dir(err)
  }

   console.log('Connected to MongoDB')

  //get the collection
  let db = client.db('myproject');
  db.collection('users').insertOne({
  name: 'Hello World',
  email: 'helloworld@test.com'

  },(err,result)=> {
  if(err) {
      return console.dir(err)
  }
  console.log("Inserted Document");
  console.log(result);

     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've simple solution:

note_routes.js

```
db.collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
```

replace

```
db.db().collection('notes').insert(note, (err, result) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same tutorial having the same issue. I just checked all the answers and found the one for me.

```
MongoClient.connect(db.url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) => {
var database = client.db('test');
if (err) return console.log(err) 
require('./app/routes')(app, database);
app.listen(port, () => { console.log('We are live on ' + port);}); })
```

changed database to client and define the database as client.db('test')