# How to use mongoDB with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation, mlab

When I run the script, the error returns.

> **TypeError**: db.collection is not a function

```
 var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
 var url = "mongodb://abc:12345**@xxxx.mlab.com:&&&&/myDB";
 MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);
   } else {
      console.log("Database created!");
      db.collection('users').aggregate([{
        '$match': {
          'organization.organizationId': "e1716c62-fdce-11e7-8be5-
           0ed5f89f718b"
        }
      },{
       "$project": {
          "deviceDetails": 1,
          "userDetails": 1
       }
     }], function(error, documents) {
           if (error) {
             console(error);
           } else {
           console.log(documents);
          }
        });
  });
```

Hi, could you please help me where am I doing wrong.Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: db.collection is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43779323/typeerror-db-collection-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I believe that you're using Mongo Driver 3.0 (or above) for Node.js? In that case you should not be getting a db, but a client as callback.

Comment: @NileshSingh Yes I have a mongoVersion 3.6.1, plz tell how to get 'db' in the about script

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Mongo Driver 3.0 or above, the connect callback returns `err` and `client` instead of `db`. To get the db out of the client do this,

```
var db = client.db;
```

In your case, it will look something like this,

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
   if(err) {
    console.log(err);
   } else {
      var db = client.db;
      console.log("Database created!");
      db.collection('users').aggregate(...)
   }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client))` where this was released in recent updates. For more info refer [Mongo Driver Docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html).

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
// Dont use database name in link
var url = "mongodb://abc:12345**@xxxx.mlab.com:&&&&";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        let db = client.db('myDB')
        console.log("Database created!");
        db.collection('users').aggregate([{
            '$match': {
                'organization.organizationId': "e1716c62-fdce-11e7-8be5-0e d5f89f718b "
            }
        }, {
            "$project": {
                "deviceDetails": 1,
                "userDetails": 1
            }
        }], function(error, documents) {
            if (error) {
                console(error);
            } else {
                console.log(documents);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should check that database connect or not only run this code so that this confirm that variable url is correct or mongodb is correctly installed.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {         
 if (err)

          {
              console.log("Failed connecting to the database.  " + err);
          } 
          else
          {
           console.log(Sucessfully)

           }
});
```