# Mongoose Check If Collection Exist

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying insert 800 objects into mongodb also I'm trying to prevent inserting same elements again and again. I will check if collection exist, don't insert, else insert 800 objects.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDB', function(err,db){
  if(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
  db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections){
    console.log(collections);
  });
});
```

But console throws and error and it says:

```
(node:24452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: db.listCollections is not a function
(node:24452) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I'm stuck right now, thanks.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444876/node-js-mongoose-check-if-a-collection-exists) works for you.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'listCollections' of undefined

Comment: Looks like your connection object db is not defined

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694265/2683814) is related to your issue. You have to get the db object from the db by passing your db name. The db in the url if for login database.

Answer (score 2):

listCollections function is available on client.db, have you tried this?

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDB', function(err, client) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    client.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, collections) {
        console.log(collections);
    });
});
```